# Order to execute method while loading JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, execution

I've got 2 Controllers.

**FirstController**

One will go to the DB and make a count(*) to see how many messages are unread.

**SecondController**

The other will open the message and when it opens, if it is unread, it'll be marked as read.

---

The problem that i'm facing is that when I open the JSF page, it executes first the firstcontroller and then the second one. So it does not refresh how many messages I still have unread.

Is it possible to set an order to execute methods while opening the page?

The page looks like a left side menu, that contains how many messages are unread, and in the center will open the message.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't exactly give any details on how "JSF executes the firstcontroller". Is this via a `preRenderViewEvent` handler, a `@PostConstuct` method, or what?

From you problem description, it sounds like the order already happens to be correct? You say that the firstcontroller is executed, and this `FirstController` checks for unread messages. So messages are being 'refreshed'. But then you say that it does not refresh the unread messages, so which is it?

Regardless, a single JSF view (page) is best backed by a single backing bean. This single backing bean orchestrates calls to different services (e.g. EJB beans) and prepares all required data. The view then binds to this backing bean only to fetch its data.

With this setup you won't run in any execution order problems at all.

Comment: The firstcontroller works properly but it should be executed after the second one. that's the main problem.
The firstcontroller is "@RequestScoped" and the second is "@ViewScoped". And there methods are all executed in a "@PostConstruct" method. I believe they execute by the time they load. But I'd like to switch if possible.

Comment: It would have the same problem if they were in same Controller.

Comment: Why do you think you have the same problem if all methods were in the same backing bean?

Comment: Because the problem is the order that the methods are being executed, and they are being executed as they load. So, if we put them together in one bean, it will execute the first method before than the second method. Because it's loaded before.

Comment: Then either don't execute them as they load and load everything upfront in your @PostConstruct method, or do an extra check if you specifically want to lazy load. But realize that all information the page has, your backing bean can also have, so whatever decision can be made there can also be made in the backing bean. But maybe you should show some example code? It's not very clear what your exact problem is now.

Comment: @pringlessin: if you have a single method in java that calls two other methods in the normal way (not async) the order is fixed. It's impossible for them to somehow be called in a different order!